# Is it possible to have XP Mode in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 Home Prem 32-bit with 2GB RAM.

I have some older software that won't run so am wondering if i can run XP Mode?

Is it only possible if you have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate?

If that is the case is there any other way to do something similar or will i need to install XP on another HD or partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your problem with XP Mode was because your computer doesn't support Virtualization:

[image]

This problem is now over. See this ghacks article:
[Windows 7 Patch Removes Hardware Virtualization Requirement Of Windows XP Mode](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/03/20/windows-7-patch-removes-hardware-virtualization-requirement-of-windows-xp-mode/).

To quote:

> Install this update to remove the
>   prerequisites required to run Windows
>   Virtual PC and XP mode
>
> Update for Windows 7 ([KB977206](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=837f12aa-1d37-464e-ae59-20c9ecbebaf6&displaylang=en))
>   Update for Windows 7 for x64-based
>   Systems ([KB977206](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e70dd043-e262-43c0-a002-446567f1e2b4&displaylang=en))

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try this tomorrow and post back the outcome.  My initial concern was that xp mode seemed to be for Win7 Pro and upwards based on browsing MS's site.  Your replies suggest not so i will investigate.  Thankyou.

Comment: Here's one more article you need : Workaround to Install Windows XP Mode in Windows 7 Home Premium and Home Basic, here : http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/12/14/workaround-to-install-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7-home-premium-and-home-basic/

Answer (score 0):

Ok well to answer my own question it would appear that although i could download virtual PC and XP mode the latter will not work.

Here's a MS social post with more details...
http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7programs/thread/269ebcb5-5b28-4d87-8b5b-392ab797235c

Installing XP SP3 seems to be the best option then

Comment: According to this How To Geek article (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11060/create-an-xp-mode-for-windows7-home-versions-and-vista/) you can make one yourself ;-)

Comment: and if you don't have hardware virtualization (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10911/run-xp-mode-on-windows-7-machines-without-hardware-virtualization/) there are still ways to get it working!